# Как отфильтровать поле через stream

Tags: java, json, java-stream

Из сети получаю json файл и должен прочитать список весь и вернуть только те факты, у которых поле голосов не равно null (фильтр надо сделать через stream).

С сетью я разобрался, а вот как прочесть список и сделать фильтр поля через stream не понимаю.

Может кто подскажет. Заранее спасибо

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


public class Main {
    public static final String REMOTE_SERVICE_URI = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/netology-code/jd-homeworks/master/http/task1/cats";
    public static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .setUserAgent("Service")
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                        .setSocketTimeout(3000)
                        .setRedirectsEnabled(false)
                        .build())
                .build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(REMOTE_SERVICE_URI);
        request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        Arrays.stream(response.getAllHeaders()).forEach(System.out::println);
        String body = new String(response.getEntity().getContent().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(body);
        List<ReformJson> reformJsons = mapper.readValue(response.getEntity().getContent(),
                new TypeReference<>() {

                }
        );
        reformJsons.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ReformJson {
    private final int userId;
    private final int id;
    private final String title;
    private final String body;


    public ReformJson(
            @JsonProperty("userId") int userId,
            @JsonProperty("id") int id,
            @JsonProperty("title") String title,
            @JsonProperty("body") String body
    ) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post" + "" +
                "\n  userId=" + userId +
                "\n  id=" + id +
                "\n  title=" + title +
                "\n  body=" + body;
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, какое из полей объекта `ReformJson` относится к голосам, поэтому в следующем примере список `List<ReformJson>` отфильтруем по полям `body` - чтобы они были не null и не пустые:

```java
List<ReformJson> reformJsons = mapper.readValue(
        response.getEntity().getContent(), new TypeReference<>() {}
    )
    .stream()
    .filter(rj -> Objects.nonNull(rj.getBody()) && !rj.getBody().isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Но мне почему то идея не дает реализовать это как у Вас. У меня выдает ошибку

Comment: Какого рода ошибку?

Comment: И где в объекте `ReformJson` поле с голосами?

Comment: такого поля по условиям задачи нет. я думаю эти данные входят в поле body.

Comment: может надо его создать было

Comment: условие задачи: _Из сети получаю json файл и должен прочитать список весь и вернуть только те факты, у которых **поле голосов** не равно null_  Вы же выводите в коде содержимое `body` и содержимое списка `ReformJson`, почему не указать это в вопросе, чтобы не приходилось заниматься гаданием, создано ли это поле и кому его нужно создавать?  Если вы хотите какой-то помощи, не стоит скрывать существенную информацию.  Здесь мало телепатов и ясновидящих.

Comment: Информацию об "ошибке" вы также не предоставили.